# CLang LibTooling handling function Template arguments

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I want to handle template arguments diffrently so for the code:

```
template <class T> class A { 
public:
     A() {} 
};

void faa(A<int>& param);
```

I would like to know that param is a template specialisation and get access it's parameters.

So I wrote an `ASTVisitor` with function

```
 bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
    std::cout<< "VisitFunctionDecl" <<std::endl;

    const DependentTemplateSpecializationType* t1;
    const TemplateSpecializationType* t2;
    for(ParmVarDecl* p :f->params())
    {

        t1=p->getType()->getAs<DependentTemplateSpecializationType>();

        t2=p->getType()->getAs<TemplateSpecializationType>();

        if(t1!=nullptr||t2!=nullptr)
        {
            std::cout<< "template param found" <<std::endl;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But those casts are both `nullptr` always - I never get the `template param found` output.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to cast t to some king of type allowing checking of the template parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `A<int>&` is `LValueReference` (can be checked with [`getTypeClassName()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html#aa35ef4b312a33fc6ff11c6faf546cd1f)). What you are probably trying to get is type pointed by reference. You can get it with [`getNonReferenceType()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html#ab6a2e89b5fcb1618aaef3a38563b10e4)   method.

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
    llvm::errs() << "VisitFunctionDecl:" << f->getQualifiedNameAsString()
            << "\n";
    for (ParmVarDecl* p : f->params()) {

        llvm::errs() << p->getType().getAsString() << " -> "
                << p->getType()->getTypeClassName() << "\n";
        llvm::errs() << "isPointerType: "
                << p->getType()->hasPointerRepresentation() << "\n"
                << "isTemplateSpecialization: "
                << (nullptr != p->getType().getNonReferenceType()->getAs<
                                TemplateSpecializationType>()) << "\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

output is:

```
VisitFunctionDecl:faa
const A<int> & -> LValueReference
isPointerType: 1
isTemplateSpecialization: 1
```